# Prototype: how to get new input value after some key pressed?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I would like to check an email after customer pressed any key. This is my code:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
   $('billing:email').observe('keypress', function(event){
        console.log(event.element().value);
   });
});
```

If I press "D" log will print "".
If I press "S" after "D" was pressed - log will print "D".

How to get actual current input value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try the `input` event instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input). The classic key/up/down/press events are can be murky when trying to also read input changes. Seems that `keypress` fires before the character prints. But you'll also miss other events such as users backspacing over text. [Quirks mode has the gory details.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)

Comment: this is not cross-browser event. And it doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: You don't specify what specific browsers you want, but it works for me in Chrome/IE just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/stofte/DpYBZ/

Answer (score 1):

Try it on the `keyup` event and also `this` is set to the element the event happened on so you can clean it up to

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
   $('billing:email').observe('keyup', function(){
        console.log(this.value);
   });
});
```